# Particles.js not showing on mobile connected to localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I am working with `particles.js` which I have successfully implemented in my website.

I tried to view the website on my mobile device by connecting my laptop to the mobile hotspot running on my phone. When I visit the site on my phone, everything is okay but `particles.js` is not running.

Anyone with a fix around this?

Comment: Refer to: [`How do I ask a question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) prior to asking open-ended questions.

Comment: Show your code so we can determine what is overriding if anything, As well, be sure to check console to see if you have an explicit error.